# "Другие, еще и незнакомые люди". Нужна ли запятая после "незнакомые"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая после “незнакомые”? Если да, то почему?

**"Странное чувство только было, когда туда другие, еще и незнакомые(,) люди заехали".**

Comment: После "другие" забыл поставить запятую.

Comment: Кнопка <Править> разве не работает?

Answer (score 1):

**Странное чувство только было, когда туда другие, еще и незнакомые люди заехали.**

Можно сделать перестановку: **Странное  только чувство  было, когда туда заехали другие, еще и незнакомые люди.**

Между определениями пояснительные отношения, но они оформляются как однородные (ставится одна запятая).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится: **Он заговорил совсем другим, серьёзным тоном.**

Answer (score 1):

Сразу не обратил внимание на *и*: "еще **и** незнакомые". Это меняет суть дела. Люди другие, а к тому же еще и незнакомые. Теперь нельзя говорить, что отношения пояснительные. У нас **присоединительная** конструкция. Фраза стилистически неудачна, но если ничего не менять, то присоединительную конструкцию нужно обособлять:

**Странное чувство только было, когда туда другие, еще и незнакомые, люди заехали.**

А еще лучше ее изменить, например так:

**Странное чувство только было, когда туда другие, к тому же еще и незнакомые, люди заехали.**

А еще лучше так:

**Странное чувство только было, когда туда другие люди заехали, к тому же еще и незнакомые.**